# VBA: Only add unique values to excel combobox, which is populated by looping through a source sheet range on workbook open

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

The below code basically looks at a source sheet on workbook open, takes the values from a range and loops through adding each value to a combobox.

What I want to do is include some code to ensure only unique values, i.e. no dupes, are added.

Any ideas how I can get that working?

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim Home As Worksheet
Dim Datasource As Worksheet


'Define Variables and dropdown object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MIDCell As Range


Dim ComboMID As ComboBox


Set Home = ActiveSheet
Set Home = Worksheets("UPDATER")
Set Datasource = wb.Sheets("LaunchCodes")


'asign dropdown object to combobox
Set ComboMID = Home.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object


'Empty the combobox currnetly to avoid duplicating content
ComboMID.Clear



'With and For loop to put all values in games launch code column, ignoring any blanks,  into combobox
With Datasource
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each MIDCell In .Range("D2:D1000" & LastRow)
         If MIDCell.Value <> "" Then
            ComboMID.AddItem MIDCell.Value
           
    End If
    
Next
End With



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below avoids looping through cells in a worksheet because it's slow. Actually, that process can be sped up by reading the list into a variable (as, in fact, my code also does) but using Excel's own `RemoveDuplicates` method appears more efficient.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' 155

    Dim Wb          As Workbook
    Dim ComboMid    As ComboBox
    Dim TmpClm      As Long                 ' number of temporary column
    Dim Arr         As Variant              ' unique values from column D
    
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    With Wb.Worksheets("UPDATER")
        Set ComboMid = .OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
        With .UsedRange
            TmpClm = .Column + .Columns.Count
        End With
    End With
    
    With Wb.Sheets("LaunchCodes")
        ' create a copy of your data (without header) in an unused column
        .Cells(2, "D").CurrentRegion.Copy .Cells(1, TmpClm)
        .Cells(1, TmpClm).CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        Arr = .Cells(1, TmpClm).CurrentRegion.Value
        .Columns(TmpClm).ClearContents
    End With
    
    With ComboMid
        .List = Arr
        .ListIndex = 0                      ' assign first list item to Value
    End With
End Sub
```

You don't need to clear the combo box in the above code because replacing the `List` property with a new array automatically removes whatever it was before.

Answer (score 0):

### Unique to ComboBox

- To learn about the combo box study [this](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Fill_combobox_listbox_en.html).

You can replace the code after the line `Set ComboMID = Home.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object` with the following snippet:

```
Dim rng As Range
With DataSource
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("D2:D" & lastrow)
End With
Dim Unique As Variant
Unique = getUniqueFromRange(rng)
If Not IsEmpty(Unique) Then
    ComboMID.List = Unique
End If
```

which uses the following function:

```
Function getUniqueFromRange( _
    rng As Range) _
As Variant
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rng.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
        Data = rng.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
    cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            For j = 1 To cCount
                cValue = Data(i, j)
                If Not IsError(cValue) And Not IsEmpty(cValue) Then
                    .Item(cValue) = Empty
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        If .Count > 0 Then
            getUniqueFromRange = .Keys
        End If
    End With
    
End Function
```